# React reconciliation on array and siblings loses focus

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I've had this bug in my app where an input would lose focus when an update was made into the DOM tree. I know, pretty common bug, however I couldn't find my specific case, as I was using keys correctly, I wasn't creating any component in my render method, etc. etc.

I've found the solution to my case: While some of the inputs were rendered through `list.map(...)`, the affected one was added as a sibling, next to this array.

An example can be found here https://codesandbox.io/s/6y7ok9km3w, but in summary:

What not to do:

```
  <div>
    {this.state.values.map((v, i) => <input value={v} key={i} />)}
    <input
      value=""
      key={this.state.values.length}
      onChange={this.onChange}
    />
  </div>
```

Solution

```
  <div>
    {this.state.values
      .map((v, i) => <input value={v} key={i} />)
      .concat([
        <input
          value=""
          key={this.state.values.length}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
      ])}
  </div>
```

It seems as if react would ignore the `key` of a sibling element just because it's not in an array? Does anyone know what's going on in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in React document:

> Keys only make sense in the context of the surrounding array.

So what you say is correct

> React would ignore the key of a sibling element just because it's not in an array

The key of the input element that is not in the array will be ignore. And for the record you should not use index as key as much as you can. If you want to know more about the risk visit https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318 for more

Comment: Ty! Yep, in my project I'm using model ids, but I took these out in my example to make it easier to understand (and I'm doing something cool where the key of the "empty" input is the id of the next model, that hasn't been created yet.